# How to show/hide a button from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and C#, I tried few things but did not worked. I have an .aspx page where I have three buttons, as shown in below code:

```
<body>
<form id="htmlForm" runat="server">  
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="rsm" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1800" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="rap" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="ralp">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Invoice Download
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Invoice Start #
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntbStart" Runat="server" MaxValue="1000000" MinValue="1000" Width="75px" >
                        <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" />
                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Invoice End #
                </td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntbEnd" Runat="server" MaxValue="1000000" MinValue="1000" Width="75px" >
                        <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" />
                    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" />
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDownloadSAP" runat="server" Text="Download SAP" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="ralp" Runat="server" Skin="Default" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnConform" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Conform Download" OnClick="btnConform_Click" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to do that `btnConform` will be initially invisible while the page is loading and now if I click `cmdDownload` or `cmdDownloadSAP`, button `btnConform` must get visible. Now if I click again on `btnConform` it will become invisible.

I cannot use JavaScript because `cmdDownload` and `cmdDownloadSAP` have some other task to complete before I make `btnConform` visible (say database call) and the `btnConform` will become visible only if the database call is successful.

```
   partial class XPO_Accounting_InvoiceDownload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

protected void cmdDownload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Session["InvoiceStart"] = rntbStart.Value;
    Session["InvoiceEnd"] = rntbEnd.Value;
    try
    {
        //All DB call
                    btnConform.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblResult.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}

protected void cmdDownload0_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Session["InvoiceStart"] = rntbStart.Value;
    Session["InvoiceEnd"] = rntbEnd.Value;
    try
    {
        //All DB call   
                    btnConform.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblResult.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    cmdDownload.Click += cmdDownload_Click;
    cmdDownloadSAP.Click += cmdDownload0_Click;
}
protected void btnConform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double InvoiceStart = (double)Session["InvoiceStart"];
    double InvoiceEnd = (double)Session["InvoiceEnd"];

    try
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(XPOStaticData.Instance.SQL, CommandType.Text, "update tblInvoiceNum set uploadedtoacct = 'Y' WHERE Status='I' AND InvoiceNum BETWEEN " + InvoiceStart + " AND " + InvoiceEnd + " and uploadedtoacct = 'N'");
        lblResult.Text = "Downloaded Invoiced has conformed as the correct one.";
        btnConform.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblResult.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

This does not work.
Sorry for change the content of the question (cause older content wasn't pointing the problem properly). This is actual code here I'm trying to do it. (it looks stupid to pest the complete code...)

Comment: Whenever you want to do it server side, a postback will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Visible` property to the `Button` using markup to initially set the second button's visibility:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" Text="One" OnClick="btnOne_Click" />

 <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="Two" OnClick="btnTwo_Click" />
```

And on the event handlers, add this:

```
protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnTwo.Visible = true;
}

protected void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnTwo.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: He does not want Button 1 to be invisible When Button 1 is clicked

Comment: @captainsac: Sorry, misinterpreted the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You change visibility with the [`Visible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //require code to make it visible
    btnTwo.Visible = true;
}


protected void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //require code to make it invisible
    btnTwo.Visible = false;
}
```

If you want to make a server control initially invisible you also have to use this property, so you can either use codebehind to change visibility programmatically ore declaratively on the aspx-page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Two" OnClick="btnTwo_Click" />
```

One final note, `Visible=false` on serverside means that this control **is not rendered at all on client-side**. So it does simply not exist and can not be accessed (or made visible) on client-side.

If you need to access it on client-side you should make it invisible via stylesheets either by using

- `display: none`(does not take up any space) or
- `visibility: hidden`(still takes up space in the layout).

---

**Update** acc. to the last edit of your  question the event handlers don't seem to be registered anymore.

So you need:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdDownload" OnClick="cmdDownload_Click" runat="server" Text="Download" />
<asp:Button ID="cmdDownloadSAP" OnClick="cmdDownload0_Click" runat="server" Text="Download SAP" />
```

Comment: I did this in a sample app it does work. but the app where I'm trying to do I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: @rahulchrty: If you set a break point on the event handlers, do they get hit?

Comment: @rahulchrty: maybe you have code in your app which already controls visibility, for example in `Page_Load`. It's difficult to help without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made some changes to the question I hope this will explain my problem

Comment: @rahulchrty: you have not registered the event handlers in your current code, have you? Have you used the debugger to check if the code is executed at all? Maybe an exception prevents the final change of the visibility. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @rahulchrty: `OnClick` is a serverside event which you can't register via `Attributes.Add`. `Visible` is also a serverside property which doesn't work on clientside, so you cannot use it with javascript.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I faced no exception at all.

btnConform.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + btnConform.ClientID + ".Visible=false;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnConform, ""));
   btnConform.Visible = false;

I solved the problem by this away (I put this in OnInit then button becomes invisible initially then every download button I put the same code but changing Visible=true).
But yet I'm able to get why the posted code was not working as expected :-( . I just assumed that because of ajax call using telerik...

Comment: You don't get a direct exception because it's just a string, but you'll get a js-exception because there is no `Visible` method on client-side.